# How can I retrieve the absolute filename in a shell script on Mac OS X?

Tags: mac-osx, bash, shell

I'd like to retrieve the absolute file name of the script file that's currently executed. Links should be resolved, too.

On Linux, this seems to be done like this:

```
$(readlink -mn "$0")
```

but `readlink` seems to work **very** differently on Mac OS X.

I've read that this is done using

```
$(realpath $0)
```

in BSD but that doesn't work, either. Mac OS X does not have `realpath`.

Any idea?

Comment: See this question over on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799679/programatically-retrieving-the-absolute-path-of-an-os-x-command-line-app

Comment: And this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055671/how-can-i-get-the-behavior-of-gnus-readlink-f-on-a-mac

Comment: Even more options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665/how-to-resolve-symbolic-links-in-a-shell-script

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I cheat and use perl for this very thing:

```
#!/bin/bash
dirname=`perl -e 'use Cwd "abs_path";print abs_path(shift)' $0`
echo $dirname
```

You'd think I'd just write the entire script in perl, and often I do, but not always.

Comment: This works, thanks a lot. I'll give you an upvote as soon as I can.
Does anyone have a "pure shell" way of doing this?

Comment: I'm afraid this is as good as it gets. (Given the many multiple-line "pure shell" hacks one can find on Google.)

Comment: another possibility (though ugly) is to traverse the '..' path, memorizing (thru recursion or an array) until '..' returns the same file you just had (ie: you are at the top), then come back assembling the path as you go.  I've seen Legato's Networker backup software doing this during strace as a method of obtaining a 'true' path (but perhaps not absolute).  But it would be a lot more code than the above.

Comment: Not sure why someone modifed the code to use $1 instead of $0.
Isn't $1 the first arg to the bash script?
I wanted the path to the executing bash script, not it's first argument.

Answer (score 32):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
scriptDir="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd -P)"
```

Comment: Works in MacOSX too.

Comment: This is super! There are many other over-complicated answers floating around.

Comment: This only works for files in a symlinked directory, not for symlinked files in general

Comment: It's also helpful to `unset -v CDPATH` prior to the cd since cd can cause unwanted output if CDPATH is set.

Comment: To deal with at least a single layer of symlinking of the file, you can also test in a compatible way with readlink (macs don't have -f):  `scriptDir=$(unset -v CDPATH; cd "$(dirname "$(readlink "$BASH_SOURCE" || echo "$BASH_SOURCE)")" && pwd -P)`

Answer (score 1):

This handles combos of symlinks, and it works on files and folders:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
realpath()
{
    if ! pushd $1 &> /dev/null; then 
        pushd ${1##*/} &> /dev/null
        echo $( pwd -P )/${1%/*}
    else
        pwd -P
    fi
    popd > /dev/null
}
```

But it does not support realpath's --relative-to. This would require the conversion  [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12498485/869951).

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
# Install.
brew install coreutils

# Use the GNU variant.
grealpath --help
```